# PhoneGap/Cordova: Libs does not exist

Tags: android, cordova

I've just downloaded Cordova, along with all the requirements for Android and Windows Phone. I can successfully build a WP8 image and send it to my 8X, however, I can't seem to be able to build an Android image.

When I execute `cordova build android`, I get the following error:

Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
    Preparing android project
    Compiling app on platform "android" via command "cmd" /c Y:\mobile\platforms\android\cordova\build

```
C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while building the android project.
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\compile.js:65:22)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:948:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

And when I launch the build command manually, I get the following error:

```
Error executing "ant debug -f "Y:\mobile\platforms\android\build.xml"":
BUILD FAILED
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:962: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:973: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:313: com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: Y:\mobile\platforms\android\bin\rs
Libs does not exist
        at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.getNativeFiles(ApkBuilder.java:742)
        at com.android.ant.ApkBuilderTask.execute(ApkBuilderTask.java:303)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
```

It seems that the cordova-3.3.0.jar file doesn't get compiled, shouldn't it get compiled automatically? Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the whole Android project, recompiled the CordovaLibs and recompiled the Android project. Seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be an error with Ant. I had this error because I forgot to change the **environment variable** path.

The path I added was wrong (you need to specify this folder: "way\to\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin"). I just changed it and it works now.

(If it's not that, it can be an other path environment variable such as node, or your java sdk or android sdk)

Hope it can help someone.

Answer (score -2):

try commands

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
```